# 3 columns to align correctly with divs

Tags: css, templates, html, joomla

Hows it going. 
Im just started to learn a bit about joomla and Im trying to get my divs to align vertically when making a template.
The problem is that the right div is way down the bottom of the page on the right hand side and the center div is aligned at least 1 character height below the left div which is the only one correctly aligned. I also cant see the footer div (maybe because the image is plain black along with the text.)
The left, right, center and footer div are within a container div. I previewed it in firefox and although the container image and borders are exactly where i want them, the div contents are all over the place.
Heres the css code, any help with this would be great. Ill also paste the Div ids and structure below the css awell.
Thanks in advance.

```
body{
margin: 0 auto;
background-color: #000000;
background-repeat: repeat;
text-align: center;}

#container {
width: 900px;
height: 759px;
margin: 0 auto;
border-left: 5px #ffffff solid;
border-right: 5px #ffffff solid;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-image: url(../slices/images/images/content-slice.jpg);}

#searchbox{

}

#header{
width: 900px;
height: 104px;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-image: url(../slices/Sf-Head-slice.jpg);
margin: 0 auto;
border-left: 5px #ffffff solid;
border-right: 5px #ffffff solid;
text-align: left;}

#header2{
width: 900px;
height: 108px;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-image: url(../slices/searchboxwithplayer-slice.jpg);
margin: 0 auto;
border-left:5px #ffffff solid;
border-right:5px #ffffff solid;
text-align: left;}

#footer{
width: 900px;
text-align: left;
margin: 0 auto;
height: 28px;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-image: url(../slices/images/footerslice.jpg);}

#left{
text-align: left;

margin: 0 auto;
width: 220px;
height: 752px;
float: left;}

#right{
text-align: left;
margin: 0 auto;
width: 220px;
height: 752px;
float: right;}

#center{
text-align: left;
margin: 0 auto;
height: 752px;
width: 400px;
}
```

Heres the divs

```
<body>
  <div id="header">this is the header</div>
  <div id="header2">this is header2
<div id="searchbox">this is the searchbox
</div>
</div>
  <div id="container">this is the container
<div id="left">this is the left column</div>
<div id="center">this is the center column</div>
<div id="right">this is the right column</div>
<div id="footer">this is the footer</div>
</div>
</div>

</body>
```

Answer (score 2):

The reason the columns aren't lining up beside each other is because the center column isn't floated.  The margin: 0 auto also isn't helping things.  The rule with floating columns is to make sure that the sum of all element widths you want beside each other is <= the width of their container.  In your case you'll be ok because:

```
220 + 220 + 400 < 900
```

Once you float all the columns and then clear with the footer, you should be in business.  I also changed how your footer background image is repeating based on the name (I'm assuming it's a thin slice that you want to tile horizontally).

```
#footer{
    clear: both;
    text-align: left;
    height: 28px;
    background: url(../slices/images/footerslice.jpg) repeat-x top left;
}

#left, #right, #center {
    text-align: left;
    height: 752px;
    width: 220px;
}

#left {
    float: left;
}

#right {
    float: right;
}

#center{
    float: left;
    width: 400px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have no experience with Joomla and my CSS knowledge is to crude to supply a real answer, but if you want a working multi column layout you should definitely take a look at [YAML](http://www.yaml.de/en/home.html) (not the YAML language, thats another thing). Maybe you can take their CSS partky or as a whole. Even if you can't, their [documentation](http://www.yaml.de/en/documentation.html) is very descriptive and will teach you a lot about the caveats related to multi column layouts.